# VB.net Unique Hardware ID ideas

Tags: .net, vb.net, hardware

I was wondering if there would be anything else I could use in my Hardware ID protection that would make it much more unique.

I am currently using

- Processor ID
- Volume ID
- MAC Address
- Graphics Card Name

If you guys can provide source codes to anything else that would make it even more unique please tell me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I upgraded my graphics card more than once. If this were to break a completely unrelated app, I would be *very emphatically and vocally unhappy*, especially if the makers of such software were still in business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest using the HDD Serial Number instead of the Volume ID.

The Volume ID will change if you format your HDD but the HDD Serial Number will not.

http://addressof.com/blog/archive/2004/02/14/386.aspx

Comment: "HDD Serial Number instead of the Volume ID" -  -  - Agree

Comment: Please, don't do this.  While there is no perfect solution, replacing hard drives seems way more common then some others.  I've had many customers be totally boned when their hard drive died and then some proprietary software made by an out-of-business company refused to activate on the new drive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a library that can read the [unique hardware ID](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20ID%20programmer%27s%20DLL.html) of you computer. MAC address is not good because it can be changed, unless you read it from hardware NOT from Windows.

Comment: Not only that, but you can't be sure the computer even has a network interface.

Comment: Or even more than one network interface in the case of a laptop with a wired and wireless connection